# Could a foreign key property be a part of a composite primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

Following the TPC pattern.
I've one abstract class called Entity which is inherited by Person and LegalEntity.

```
public abstract class Entity
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }

public class LegalEntity : Entity
  {
     public string CorporateName { get; set;}
  }

public class Person : Entity
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

I've also another one  called Agent which have many children. For simplification i'll show only one class Subscriber.

```
public  abstract class Agent
  {
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
  }

 public  class Subscriber : Agent
  {
    public string Number { get; set; }
    
    public Entity Entity { get; set; } // No EntityId here because the foreign key correspond to the Id of Subscriber
  }
```

Below  the configuration of my entities :

```
public AgentConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(s => new { s.EntityId, s.RoleId });
        ...
    }

public SubsbcriberConfiguration()
   {
       Map(m =>
            {
               m.MapInheritedProperties();
               m.ToTable("T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR");
             }
         
            **.WithMany() //I don't want a property on the other side 
          .HasForeignKey(s => s.EntityId); // EF doesn't accept to put the property Id as a foreign key.**

   }

    public EntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id_personne");
        ...
     }

    public PersonConfiguration()
    {
        Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("T_PERSONNE_PHYSIQUE");
        });
     }
```

I have a  One to One relationship between the abstract class Entity and the concrete class Subscriber.
The primary key of the class Entity is at the same time a part of the composite primary key of the Subscriber and a foreign key.

**Is it possible to configure this scenario?**

When i declare the property Id as a foreign key, EF throws an exception like below :

> The foreign key component 'EntityId' is not a declared property on type 'Subscriber'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

I tried many scenarios, but i didn't find a solution because i have a one to one relationship but the tables have different keys and the foreign key is a part of the composite primary key.

How can i configure a property as a foreign key and also  a part of a composite primary key in code first?

What am I missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

## Edit :

I broke up the inheritance of the class Agent and the TPC. Now the class Subscriber has no parent. when i configure it like below :

```
  public SubsbcriberConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(s => new { s.EntityId, s.RoleId });
        Property(s => s.EntityId).HasColumnName("id_personne")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(s => s.RoleId).HasColumnName("id_role")
             .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        ...
        ToTable("T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR");
        
        HasRequired(s => s.Entity)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(s => s.EntityId)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Entity Framework is looking for another foreign key : ***column Extent1.Entity_Id does not exist***

And the query generated by EF when i try to load a subscriber is :

```
`SELECT 
   "Extent1"."id_personne",
   "Extent1"."id_role",
    ...
   "Extent1"."Entity_Id"
 FROM "T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR" AS "Extent1"
 WHERE "Extent1"."id_personne" = ((73660)) AND 
   "Extent1"."id_role" = ((4))`
```

I don't know how to explain to EF that the foreign key property EntityId is the foreign key.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: The Entity and Subscriber relationship is an "One to One" or "One to Many"?

Comment: `WithMany()` is used for 1:n relationships

Comment: @FabioLuz In Entity Framework, when you have a One to One relationship with different keys between the entities you have to follow this hack, it's also called "One-to-One Foreign Key Associations". see this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations). If i had the same key, i would use the hasRequiRed().WithOptional() technique...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if I understand your scenario, but this might be helpful.

Entities:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Agent
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}

public class Subscriber : Agent
{
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
        .HasKey(e => e.EntityId);

    //map the Subscriber, not the Agent
    modelBuilder.Entity<Subscriber>()
        .HasKey(a => new { a.EntityId, a.RoleId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Subscriber>()
        .HasRequired(i => i.Entity)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.EntityId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);         

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Be aware that it is an **"One-to-Many"** relationship, not **One-to-One**. The article you posted on your comment uses UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS to "simulate" the 1:1 relationship in a 1:n relationship. I don't think it is a good approach.

However, let's suppose that you want to follow that way. Where would you put the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT? The FK is part of the composite PK. If you put an UNIQUE CONSTRAINT there, it would break the PK.

Considering that the PK is composed by two columns, and the FK is composed by 1 column of the PK, I don't see how a real 1:1 relationship can be possible. Because to have a 1:1 relationship, the FK column must be the same of PK column.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The Entity Agent doesn't have it's own Id, it has the id of the class Entity.

Comment: It is just the name of the property. I edited the answer. Please, check it out.

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't undersantand that the property EntityId is the foreign key of the entity Entity and i have the following exception: The foreign key component 'EntityId' is not a declared property on type 'Subscriber'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

Comment: I've changed the entities. See the answer

Comment: I think you can't configure with code first  a property to be a foreign key and a part of a composite primary key :-(

Comment: You can, but not if the relationship is 1-1.

Comment: what do you mean? I tried this :                                                    HasRequired(s => s.Entity)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(s => s.EntityId);  and it doesn't work. Do you have another alternative?

Comment: I tried here, and it worked fine. Maybe you are missing something. Have you tried to copy the code in my answer? just for testing purposes.

Comment: May be it's because i'm following the TPC pattern and the Entity is abstract and has many children :-(